# Numbers to an extreme (Java)

Tags: java, math

EDIT: HERE IS A SCREENSHOT OF THE OUTPUT

https://www.dropbox.com/s/93d09a627se3b1u/Screenshot%202015-09-16%2019.08.19.png?dl=0]

I was recently asked to make a program that can calculate and display...

1 / (1!) + 1 / (2!) + . . . 1 / (n!)

using the Scanner utility. I seem to be having a lot of trouble with this. the program itself works, but it somehow gives the same answer no matter what number I input. Here's what I have so far (And yes, it is purposely incomplete, I'm stumped).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Power2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("I will calculate 1/(1!) + 1/(2!) . . . +   
         1/(n!)\nWhat is the value of n?");
      Double n = input.nextDouble();
      Math(n);
      System.out.println("e = " + Math.E);
   }
   public static void Math(Double E)
   {
      Double product = 1.0;
      int x = 0;
      while (E > 0)
      {    
         product = product * E;
         E--;
      }
```

Can anyone give me a way to finish/solve this problem? Thanks a ton.
~Andrew

EDIT: This code works fine for just finding the extreme. I will work on a way to add the preceding components of the equation to this, but It's a bit tricky for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Power2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("I will calculate 1/(1!) + 1/(2!) . . . + 
         1/(n!)\nWhat is the value of n?");
      Double n = input.nextDouble();
      Math(n);
      System.out.println("e = " + Math(n));
   }
   public static Double Math(Double E)
   {
      Double product = 1.0;
      while (E > 0)
      {    
         product *= E;
         E--;
      }
      return product;
   }
}
```

Comment: There's not really a point in using the `Double` wrapper. Use the simple `double` primitive type instead. Also, it's unconventional to have your method names be capitalized. Your `Math` method should be called `math`.

Comment: @LucasBaizer Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. Thats just preference.

Comment: Alright, suppose I enter 5 into the program. What would the ideal output be? What if I input 6? What you're trying to achieve here is slightly unclear.

Comment: Not really, the output is supposed to be exactly what he said: 1/(1!) + 1/(2!) + ... + 1/(n!)....so if you enter 5, you would get 1/(1!) + 1/(2!) + 1/(3!) + 1/(4!) + 1/(5!).

Comment: @LucasBaizer Just read the equation above, I want it to equate that. No matter what I input I always get an output of `e = 2.718281828459045` But this is if I just close the program's braces right there and run only what is above. I need all of the parts of the equation added together, and I can't even get one part equated.

Comment: @John3136 I was attempting to call the Math method for variable E. Is this the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the E parameter from the Math() method, but I'm not sure. This is also why Lucas said you should not capitalize your method names. `Math` happens to be a class with a constant E.

Comment: @AndrewM The value `2.718281828459045` is the mathematical number e. `Math.E` will always evaluate to this value.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused with too much `Math`.

You've got your method `Math` with a parameter `E` and the Java `Math` class with a constant `E`. You're mixing them up.

Try

```
 public static double factorial(double v)
 {
      double product = 1.0;
      while (v > 0)
      {    
         product *= v;
         v--;
      }
      return product;
  }
```

Comment: This solved the problem of getting the correct extreme! Now how to I finish the equation above? How might I add several of these together in descending order like it is in the equation?

Comment: That's a new question - try something and come back when you hit a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code:**

```
  System.out.println("e = " + Math.E);
```

**Math.E is a constant - it will always print the euler number hence your output.**

To call the the method correctly it should be

```
System.out.println("e = " + math(e)"
```

Input 1 - Output 1

Input 2 - Output 1.5

Input 3 - Output 1.66666667

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class MyClass

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("I will calculate 1/(1!) + 1/(2!) . . . +   1/(n!)\nWhat is the value of n?");
        double n = input.nextDouble();
        double solution = doMath(n);
        System.out.println("e = " + solution);
    }
    public static double doMath(double n) {

        double ret = 0;
        // the number of terms we add
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            ret += calcFaculty(i);
        }

        return ret;

    }
    // calculate every single term
    public static double calcFaculty(double d){
        double calc = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= d ; i++) {
            calc = calc* 1/i;
        }
        return calc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andrew the program always return the same number

> e = 2.718281828459045

Because the line  `System.out.println("e = " + Math.E);` is not calling the method Math but calling to the class java.lang.Math. I dont know if is this what you find dubious.

Comment: Yes I figured that out, a silly mistake. I will post new code